# PHP Function returns wrong date

Tags: php, wordpress

I' am learning how to make a WordPress Plugin. I did make few simple plugins but not as complicated as this one. It's a Events Calendar. The var_dump from the function "**nc_get_start_date()**" on the page it outputs wrong dates.

**The output from the var_dump(nc_get_start_date());**

> string(32) "1970-01-01,1970-01-01,1970-01-01"

**This is what the function should return in real**

```
23-12-2013, 25-12-2013, 26-12-2013
```

In the function.php on the plugin folder. This is the codes

```
/* Query to get the events post from the database */
    function get_nc_events(){
        global $post;
        $query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'events', 
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order' => 'ASC'
            )
        );
        return $query;
    }

/* Get the start date from the above function */
    function nc_get_start_date(){
        $query = get_nc_events();
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
            $nc_event_id = $post->ID;
            $wnc_start_date = get_post_meta( $nc_event_id, 'wnc_start_date');
            $wnc_start_date = $wnc_start_date[0];
            $wnc_start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($wnc_start_date));
            $wnc_start_date_array .= "$wnc_start_date,";
        endwhile;
        return rtrim($wnc_start_date_array, ",");
    }
```

**When I write the code in page-caledar.php without the function it renders everything prefectly.**

```
$query = get_nc_events();
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
    $nc_event_id = $post->ID;
    $wnc_start_date = get_post_meta( $nc_event_id, 'wnc_start_date');
    echo $wnc_start_date = $wnc_start_date[0] . "<br/>";
endwhile;
```

Comment: what is the value of `get_post_meta( $nc_event_id, 'wnc_start_date')`

Comment: From `get_post_meta` I get **23-12-2013, 25-12-2013, 26-12-2013**

Comment: That's the unix epoch date, which leads me to believe that $wnc_start_date[0] is 0

Comment: is that an array or string?

Comment: Yes, I' am appending it into an array

Comment: after `$wnc_start_date = get_post_meta( $nc_event_id, 'wnc_start_date');` make `return $wnc_start_date[0];`and comment the other code to see what you get

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved. Thanks everyone. The problem was in this function

```
/* Get the start date from the above function */
    function nc_get_start_date(){
        global $post;
        $query = get_nc_events();
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
            $nc_event_id = $post->ID;
            $wnc_start_date = get_post_meta( $nc_event_id, 'wnc_start_date');
            $wnc_start_date = $wnc_start_date[0];
            $wnc_start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($wnc_start_date));
            $wnc_start_date_array .= "$wnc_start_date,";
        endwhile;
        return rtrim($wnc_start_date_array, ",");
    }
```

I didn't make **global $post;**